# Can't write to Excel file from Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm trying to write to an Excel file using Python and the [xlrd module](http://www.python-excel.org/), with the following code:

```
Table = [ 'baseMax - 1cm', 'baseMin- 1cm',
          'baseMax - 5cm', 'baseMin - 5cm',
          'baseMax - 15cm' 'baseMin - 15cm'
        ]
new_base = { 'baseMax - 1cm': [], 'baseMax - 5cm': [],
             'baseMax - 15cm': [], 'baseMin- 1cm': [],
             'baseMin - 5cm': [], 'baseMin - 15cm': []
           }
HeadName = 'Base Calculation'
for i in Table:
    base_stats.write(ROW, 0, HeadName + ' ' + i + ' - ')
    base_stats_stats.write(ROW, 1, new_base[i])
    ROW = ROW+1
    ROW = ROW+1
```

When I run this code I get an error at `new_base[i]`.  I'm not sure I understand exactly what this error is about.  It appears to have to do with the parameters I'm passing, but I don't really understand it.

```
raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))
  Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'list'>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what 'base_stats', or 'base_stats_stats' represent.  Also I looked at the xlrd documentation and I see no mention of anything with a .write() method, that appears to come from the xlwt library.  Finally, your code sample has very inconsistent indentation. And the exception stuff at the end of  your post has lost me - where did it come from?

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark, and its throwing off your syntax highlighting.

Comment: I also notice that you have some variable names that aren't defined in the scope of your code here.  I don't believe those are relevant here, however it is generally important to include all necessary code for someone else to run your snippet

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your variable names and formatting are correct in your actual code.

When you're using the `write` method you're not giving it the correct parameters.

The following method prototype is found in the [xlwt module documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966): write(r, c, label="", style=Style.default_style)

The `label` parameter apparently requires a string.  When you reference `new_base[i]` you are getting back an empty list:

```
'baseXxx - Ncm':[]
```

Thus, when the `write` method looks for a string and instead gets `[]`, it throws an exception.

Comment: thanks Darren that is what i believe is the issue proper parameter passing to the write function